# Loop a batch file only 5 times

Tags: batch-file

Ive been trying to loop a batch file exactly 5 times using the set /a operation and so far no luck! Could someone help me?

```
@ECHO OFF
set loopCount=0

:loop
echo Checked %loopCount% times...
    set /a loopCount=1+%loopCount%
    if loopCount == 5 (goto exit) else (goto loop)

:exit
cls
echo Finished after %loopCount% times
pause >nul
```

Best of luck to whoever can help me

Comment: You are encountering a known bug. See [SS64 on `GOTO`](https://ss64.com/nt/goto.html) for information.

Comment: Oh no :( Thank you for the info man

Comment: `if %loopCount% equ 5`.  In any case, a `for /L` loop would be more efficient than a `goto` loop.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin, your claim is wrong! The issue is that `if loopCount == 5` should read `if %loopCount% == 5`, and that is it…

Comment: …and `set /a loopCount=1+%loopCount%` should read `set /a loopCount += 1`

Comment: @aschipfl - I saw it as being a problem with the `GOTO` in parens; I missed the syntax fail in the `IF`. Mea culpa.

Comment: @aschipfl Thank you your response was the correct syntax!

Comment: @JeffZeitlin could you possibly explain the syntax and use of 
``` for /L ```

Comment: Type `for /?` into a command prompt window and read the output text very carefully; the usage of `for /L` is also explained there…

Comment: I recommend that you bookmark [SS64 on CMD](https://ss64.com/nt/), then check their [documentation on `FOR`](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html) and specifically on [`FOR` with numbers](https://ss64.com/nt/for_l.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a couple of examples to help you.

Using `GoTo` with a label:

```batch-file
@Set "loopCount=0"

:loop
@Set /A loopCount += 1
@Rem Some actual command goes here.
@Echo Checked %loopCount% times...
@If %loopCount% Lss 5 GoTo loop
@%SystemRoot%\System32\timeout.exe /T 2 /NoBreak 1>NUL
@ClS
@Echo Finished after being checked %loopCount% times.
@Pause 1>NUL
```

Alternatively, using a `For /L` looping mechanism:

```batch-file
@Set "maxCount=5"
@For /L %%G In (1,1,%maxCount%) Do @(
    Rem Some actual command goes here.
    Echo Checked %%G times...
)
@%SystemRoot%\System32\timeout.exe /T 2 /NoBreak 1>NUL
@ClS
@Echo Finished after being checked %maxCount% times.
@Pause 1>NUL
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to execute the **entire batch script** 5 times, the following method of storing an execution count in an [alternate data stream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/askcore/alternate-data-streams-in-ntfs) of the script can be used:

```bat
@Echo off
 more < "%~f0:Count" 2>&1 > nul && (
  For /f "usebackq delims=" %%G in (`more ^< "%~f0:Count"`)Do Set /A Count=%%G+1
 ) || (
  Set /A "Count+=1"
 )
 Echo(%Count% >"%~f0:Count"

:# Your script below
Echo(Script execution: %Count%



:# Terminate script execution after count reached
 If %Count% EQU 5 (
  Echo(0 >"%~f0:Count"
  Exit /B
 )
"%~f0"
```